# Is it possible to host a Realm-Database on my own for free?

Tags: server, realm, self-hosting, realm-mobile-platform

We are doing a project which include that we have a PC-Application and an App on a Android Tablet.

The PC should be able to change/create data and the tablet should be able to receive it. We decided to use Realm as a database, or we would like to do this, however: we are students and do not have the financials to buy a Realm Cloud to host this, however, we do have a server where we could self host this.

We think that the self-host of Realm was discarded in 2018, we arn't a 100% sure however, and would be very thankful if anyone could take their time to explain.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a school project, which is very important for our grades. However, we don't want to spend a lot of money on it, as the runtime of this project is not yet determined.

Comment: https://github.com/realm ? License: The Realm Object Server and samples in the repo are proprietary and can only be used with a commercial license for self hosted Realm Object Server. Maybe mail them and ask  for support ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and the tip, I will try. :)

Comment: Not anymore since Realm Sync Platform 3.x unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the server on your own however you can't do it for free anymore. Here is the documentation for running your own realm server:

https://docs.realm.io/server/manage

Also, there is a student/long term development license for their realm cloud that is only $10 a month. It's not too much but I do understand trying to find a free version.

Answer (score 3):

The self-hosting ability of a Realm-Database was taken away, 2018.

Now you are only able to host your database of their cloud services.

Comment: Did you get this from someone at Realm? Their docs are often out of date or wrong so I'm wondering if it really is impossible to run a realm server on your own. I was under the impression that you could.

Comment: We did some more looking around and my partner found that they had decided to stop letting people self-host their Realm databases for free, you can still self-host but this costs as well now.
They posted it on their twitter.

Comment: @GBreen12 the Realm Sync Developer Edition was sunset at the release of Realm Sync 3.0 along with the introduction of the Realm Sync Platform Cloud.